# myBatis code coverage tool

Tags: code-coverage, mybatis

I am going to write code coverage tool for myBatis SQL maps.

Basically, I want to know if each statement has been called during "mvn test". The second step is to compare executed and existing statements and print difference somehow.

I wonder if it already exist because I didn't find?

Comment: I would hit up the mailing list for this question, http://groups.google.com/group/mybatis-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested in. Finally I've implemented this feature.

Just a few facts. I've created framework based on spring-test and junit. The main goal was to test myBatis statements on multiple databases at the same time.

Coverage tool is just a feature to help developer define missing tests. 
The way how coverage tool is working could be explained as following steps:

- get all statement names from myBatis once using `getMappedStatementNames()` method from `SqlMapExecutorDelegate` class.
- collect all statement names that was called.
- print difference between all and executed to the log.

There are many other improvements to this small test framework. And then all this stuff integrated into automated build system, integrated with Bamboo server etc.

At the end I've got output like this:

```
WARN  18/04/2012 15:14:50 (MultipleDatabaseRunner.java:108) COVERAGE: Statement Audit.getAudit wasn't tested.
...
```

Comment: Could you please provide your framework? I'm searching for a solution to measure test coverage of mybatis xml mapper files. Couldn't get it done with jacoco, cobertura and stuff.